# FileItem.getName() return all path of file not only file name in Java

Tags: java

I have some problem while get file Name. It always return all path of my file not only file name

```
List<FileItem> fileItemsList = uploader.parseRequest(request);
Iterator<FileItem> fileItemsIterator = fileItemsList.iterator();
while(fileItemsIterator.hasNext()){
            FileItem fileItem = fileItemsIterator.next();
            System.out.println("FileName="+fileItem.getName());
```

Output is `FileName=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\demoUpload2.war`
 but I need only `demoUpload2.war`.

Comment: What's `FileItem`?  Doesn't appear to be `java.io.File`?

Comment: Could just make that into a new File and get the name from that. `new File(fileItem.getName()).getName();`

Answer (score 3):

> Why does FileItem.getName() return the whole path, and not just the
>   file name? Internet Explorer provides the entire path to the uploaded
>   file and not just the base file name. Since FileUpload provides
>   exactly what was supplied by the client (browser), you may want to
>   remove this path information in your application. You can do that
>   using the following method from Commons IO (which you already have,
>   since it is used by FileUpload).
>       String fileName = item.getName();
>       if (fileName != null) {
>           filename = FilenameUtils.getName(filename);
>       }

Ref :http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/faq.html#whole-path-from-IE
You can do this :

```
String fileName = item.getName();
if (fileName != null) {
    filename = FilenameUtils.getName(filename);
}
```